# Is there a positive real number $\ x$ such that $x$ and $\ x+1$ both have rational roots?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that, if $x$ does exist, and $a$ and $b$ are the rational square roots of $x$ and $x+1$

$a$ and $b$ cannot be integers

$\frac{a^2}{b^2} = \frac{x}{x+1}$ implies that $\frac{x}{x+1}$ is also rational

I feel as though there are an infinite number of $x$'s that satisfy this property but I can't prove it

Comment: See related question about "consecutive powerful numbers".  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806406/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-pairs-of-consecutive-powerful-numbers-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that you are in fact looking at Pythagorean triplets notice that since $x,x+1$ have no common factors they both need to be squares. Let $x=\frac{p^2}{q^2}, x+1=\frac{r^2}{s^2}$.

This gives $$(ps)^2+(qs)^2=(qr)^2$$ There is an infinite amount of Pythagorean triplets given by:

$$(u^2-v^2)^2+(2uv)^2=(u^2+v^2)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

It is now when I realize that I should've referred to the pythagorean theorem and saw that $9/16$ and $25/16$ were one of my $x$ and $x+1$